# IOS line on an image - invert color possible?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am drawing a line on top of an UIImage in my app.  I want the line to be a "distinct" color from the background it is drawing.  If the image has white area in it, if the line is drawn on top of it it should not be white.  Is this achievable easilyt?

Now I am using white color for the line.  Code below:

```
[myImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),1,1,1, 1.0);//RGB all 1)
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), pt1.x, pt1.y);  // pt1 -start point
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), pt2.x, pt2.y); // pt2 - end point
```

As you can see I have used 1,1,1 to get white line on top of the image from point pt1 to pt2.  When this is drawn on a white area of 'myImage' the line becomes invisible.  I want to make it visible somehow on top of white as well. How can I achieve this?

Not sure whether there is already an answer to this on this forum.  But couldn't find anything like this.

Thanks in advance for your help

**EDIT**

@rob mayoff's answer wroked perfect for me.
Here is my final code for the benefit of anyone looking here:

```
[myImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),1,1,1, 1.0);//RGB all 1)

CGContextSetShadowWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f), 1.0f,
     [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:.6] CGColor]);
//CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeExclusion);
//CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeDifference);

CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), pt1.x, pt1.y);  // pt1 -start point
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), pt2.x, pt2.y); // pt2 - end point
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two suggestions:

1. Use a black shadow around your white line.  Take a look at [`CGContextSetShadowWithColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-BCIDFJGG).  You will also probably want to use `CGContextSaveGState` and `CGContextRestoreGState`, if you want to draw more things after drawing the line.
2. Set the blend mode to `kCGBlendModeDifference` or `kCGBlendModeExclusion`.  See [`CGContextSetBlendMode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-BCICDCFB).

Comment: Than you very much.  It works perfect.  All three (setshadow, BlendModeDifference and BlendModeExclusion) were working fine.  I chose the setShadow, since it was more suiting in my page.  I have added the final code as EDIT to my question.  Once again Thanks you for the help